# I want to get updated .pkl file data and using tkinter to display that live updates

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I try to create a file organizer using tkinter. Actually, In here, I have 3 tabs. and one is a customized tab. So in here user can add their file name and give an extension to which file want to input that folder. In here that data save in .pkl file. It saved it is working properly. I using my file tab to show that file names and extensions and start the process. But problem is In lively that updates are not visible in that tab. how I get that update lively from when the user input and save it. Problem summary is given below

> After the user add the inputs in customize tab. I want it that ive update
> showing in the myfile tab. It showing after reboot the update. plz
> concern that and Those customize and myfile tab pics I given below,

- Customize tab

[image: Customize tab]

- My file tab

[image: My file tab]

Comment: provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You can call a function in "My files" frame to refresh itself after saving in "Customize" frame.